# Extension of regular Baire measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a book called Banach spaces of analytic functions by Kenneth Hoffmann. In the first chapter, Measure and integration it is written that:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. A positive Baire(Borel) measure in $X$ is a function $\mu$ that assigns to every Baire(Borel) subset of $X$ a non-negative real number or $+\infty$ in such a way that

$$\mu(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n).$$

Whenever $A_1,A_2, \dots$ are disjoint Baire(Borel) subsets of $X$. The Borel measure $\mu$ is called regular, if

$$\mu(A)=\inf \mu(U)$$

the infimum is taken over all open sets $U$ containing $A$. A *Baire measure is always regular* and each *Baire measure has a unique extension to a regular Borel measure.*

I am finding it difficult to understand the *italic* parts. For the definition of Bare sets and Borel sets, I am attaching an image below.[image: Hoffmann]

Comment: Theses are the preliminaries, and are not proved there.  But it seems you are not asking for the proof. but do not understand the statements.  "A Baire measure is always regular"  and "A Baire measure has a unique extension to a regular Borel measure."  What do you not understand?  It seems to me all the terminology here is explained just above.

Comment: Thankyou @GEdgar. The first thing "A Baire measure is always regular" but do not understand the 2nd one. I do not know these preliminaries. Can you suggest me a material for the same?

Comment: The Hoffman book is from 1962, and is usnig the Halmos definition of "Baire set".  (For compact Hausdorff spaces, this coincides with the more recent definition.)  So I would guess the proofs are in the Halmos book *Measure Theory* (1950).

Comment: Thankyou@GEdgar for your help!